# Shorter Chains in blockdata

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, blockchain-fork, best-chain, stale-block

Assuming two blocks are published at exactly the same time, a race for the next block to be added to one of them begins, which eventually one chain will eventually win.

My question: will the shorter chain still be published? Does the network still syncronize the shorter chain, i.e. does every client contain a copy of not only the longest chain, but all (for lack of a better word)  "sidechains"?
If so, are there any conditions as to what will be syncronized beyond block validity?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FYI, "sidechain" has a specific meaning, and that's not it.  You are referring to what is called a "fork".  It means the network is split on which block is considered the valid one.  A sidechain is a separate blockchain altogether, that uses smart contracts to create a token on its own chain by locking one on another.

Comment: @Jestin: Please feel free to answer the actual question.

Comment: I don't actually know the specifics of how a node stores alternate forks.  I'm learning just like you are, and am also waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> will the shorter chain still be published?

Published -- no. However, if the stale tip was previously the best tip, it will be stored in a Bitcoin Core node implementation according to the [source](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/978682b9dccfb48425c0129431bb108e78e33e4e/src/net_processing.cpp#L953) and other nodes can retrieve it up to a certain point in time. The time limit is imposed to avoid fingerprinting.

> Does the network still synchronize the shorter chain.

No, the node only ever extends the active chain.